# Integral with log x calculations

Tags: calculus, integration

The integral is: $$\int_1^e x^2\log(x)\,dx$$

I don't know what to do with $\log$

Answer (score 3):

$$\int_1^e x^2\log(x)\,dx$$

Let $u = \log x \implies du = \frac 1x\,dx$.

Let $dv = x^2\,dx \implies v = \dfrac{x^3}{3}$

Now use integration by parts:

$$\int_1^e x^2\log(x)\,dx = uv - \int v \,du = \dfrac{x^3}{3}\log x\Big|_1^e - \int_1^e \dfrac{x^2}{3} dx$$

I trust you can take it from here!

Answer (score 0):

Use integration by parts with $u=\log x$ and $dv=x^2\, dx$.

Answer (score 0):

Setting $\ln x=u\implies x=e^u$

$$\int_1^ex^2\ln xdx=\int_0^1e^{2u} udu$$

Now Integrating [by parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts) , $$\int e^{2u} udu=u\int e^{2u}du-\int\left(\frac{du}{du}\cdot\int e^{2u}du\right)du$$

Can you take it home from here?